# how do i put the this data in the html?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

i am a self taught programmer/react programmer trying firebase firestore.

When i try this:

```
 var docRef = db.collection("Marcus").doc("one")

    docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());

this.setState({
    test: doc.data()
});
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
```

it works perfectly. There is no error, the document is in the console.

but when i try to add it to the input

```
class LatestNews extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            test: "input"
            }
        }

    componentDidMount() {
        docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
this.setState({
    test: doc.data()
});    

        } else {
                // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {     
        docRef.get().then(function(doc) {


               if (doc.exists) {
this.setState({
    test: doc.data()
});                } else {
                    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case


        console.log("No such document!");
            }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div> <br/><br/>
        <h1 className={Style.blue}>sup</h1>  

        <h1>{this.state.test}<News/>   </h1>
```

it does not work. IF I do it as a list, the bullet points appear for the amount of docs int he collection but none of the docs appear.

the problem I think is with either the "state.test" part or on something to do with the format of firestore not being easily transferable to HTML.

console results:

when passed into the console:
Document data: 
{Lnews: "is this working?"}
Lnews: "is this working?"
**proto**: Object

when trying to set the state with what is in the get:

Error getting document: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at LatestNews.jsx:68

Comment: neither answers solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

please use this.setState() to update the state value

```
this.setState({
    test: doc.data()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code snippet is , you are directly mutating the state. render wont't be called if you are directly mutating the state.

Fix is simple change the line :

```
 this.state.test = doc.data();
```

to

```
this.setState({
    test: doc.data()
});
```